# Parse UITableView with Search

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm following this [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/) tutorial on implementing Search; however, I'm pulling titles for the table view from Parse and can't get the search function to work. Throws an exception when I start typing in the search:

'Can't use in/contains operator with collection  {
    buildingLat = "42.726366";
    buildingLong = "-84.480642";
    buildingTitle = "International Center";
} (not a collection)'

Here's the code for my table view controller:

```
#import "BuildingsViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface BuildingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation BuildingsViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveBuildings)];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - TableView Setup

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.buildingsArray count];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [self.buildingsArray count];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"buildingsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PFObject *tempObject = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Helper Methods

-(void)retrieveBuildings
{
    PFQuery *retrieveBuildings = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"buildingsList"];
    [retrieveBuildings findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.buildingsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    self.searchResults = [self.buildingsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the oldest iOS version you must support?

Comment: Also, does the code throw in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? That is, are you able to identify (using break points / NSLog) at which line the code throws. It could be a couple of issues in the above method...

Comment: Hi Andrew, I just need to support iOS 7. I think it's because self.buildingsArray is pulling from a table in Parse where there are multiple parameters (title, latitude, longitude). What do you think?  

The line below is where the exception is being thrown (as far as I can tell).  

"self.searchResults = [self.buildingsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track...

My understanding is that you are receiving an array of dictionaries, and passing that received array to your declared `buildingsArray`. This is not the issue. The issue in my understanding is that you are then attempting to retrieve one of the values from one of those dictionaries without the appropriate code.

Your are attempting this process in two locations.

I refer to the code within your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

As an aside, it is no longer necessary to check for `cell == nil`, so you can remove the `if` statement that wraps your cell setter (`cell = [[UITableViewCell...`).

**UPDATE...**

The crash in your code when you remove this check for `nil` is due to the fact that you do not register a reuse identifier for the `searchResultsTableView`.

To correct your search and data parsing, I recommend that you follow the sample code I have included following.

Add a new property `tempMutableArray`, and remove the `static` declaration from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and place it between the `#import` and `@interface` lines as shown following...

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"buildingsCell"; // relocated static declaration 

@interface BuildingsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tempMutableArray;

@end

// implementation
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad` TVC lifecycle method, instantiate the `NSMutableArray`, and register the `UITableViewCell` class and `CellIdentifier` reuse identifier with `searchResultsTableView`...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //...your other code...

    [self setTempMutableArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] 
                                                forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

...

**YOUR NEW REPLACEMENT `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` METHOD**

To properly parse your information from Parse, try the following...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSDictionary *tempDict = nil;
        NSString *tempString = nil;

        tempDict = [self.buildingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tempString = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];

        [cell.textLabel setText:tempString];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

You will also need to complete similar in your `filterContentForSearchText:` method.

**YOUR NEW REPLACEMENT `filterContentForSearchText:` METHOD**

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = nil;

    [self.tempMutableArray removeAllObjects];
    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in self.buildingsArray) {
        NSString *tempString = nil;
        tempString = [tempDict objectForKey:@"buildingTitle"];
        [self.tempMutableArray addObject:tempString];
    }

    resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.tempMutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

**...CONTINUE WITH PREVIOUS RESPONSE**

My understanding... what is happening in your code is that your `PFQuery` returns an `NSArray` in its completion block. You set your property `buildingsArray`, also an `NSArray`, based on this. Your no longer need, as far as I understand, to treat the returned data as a `PFObject`.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response. Changing the cellForRowAtIndexPath still displays the table, so that works fine; however, I'm not sure what to do in filterContentForSearchText. Also, if I don't leave the cell == nil check, the app crashed as soon as I tap the search. Leaving it allows me to go into the search and start typing, which is where it crashes.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I made the changes and I think we're very close. It's no longer crashing when I type in the search; however, typing doesn't populate the search table. When I NSLog the self.searchResults array it keeps giving me (null). NSLogging the tempString shows the complete list no matter what characters I type, or how many. I really appreciate the help man.

Comment: LOL at myself !!! I forgot the one thing that I am constantly reminding everyone else to do - instantiate my `NSMutableArray`. I'll modify my response, hopefully that will sort out our issue.

Comment: Try the new updates - look out for a few changes in all code to manage the mutable array.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Really appreciate it. I'll mess around with the segue now.

Comment: Good news. You should delete your answer now, and when you are ready, ask a new question. Good luck.

Comment: @andrewbuilder does every search count as a new API request against parse?

Comment: @Tibbe reading through the code for this particular example, the call to Parse is made only once in the TVC lifecycle method `viewDidLoad` with the call to the custom method `retrieveBuildings`. Following that all data manipulation is against the `NSArray` local property `buildingsArray`, including all searches.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply the `NSPredicate` on an array of `PFObjects` so your predicate needs to look like this:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"variableNameToSearchOn contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];
```

EDIT:

You can try this:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"buildingTitle contains[c] %@",
                                searchText];
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to replace 'variableNameToSearchOn' with. On Parse, the title of each object is called 'buildingTitle' but that didn't work either.

Comment: @kerbelda I've updated my answer, I apologize for not being able to submit an answer I know is valid but I'm away from my computer and cannot test.

Comment: No worries, thanks for help. The second snippet doesn't work either. "buildingTitle" is actually a column in Parse. The class is called "buildingsList." I feel like I'm just not accessing the title properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
sar.showsCancelButton=YES;
sar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

}
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
NSString* newText = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
searchStr = newText;
[self DisplayMatchSearch];

[tblView reloadData];
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
//write code for requset data from database search.....
sar.showsCancelButton=NO;
[sar resignFirstResponder];

return YES;
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

[self getAlldata];

@try {
    [tblBeepUsers reloadData];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
}
[sar resignFirstResponder];
sar.text=@"";
 }

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

searchStr = sar.text;
[sar resignFirstResponder];
[self DisplayMatchSearch];
[tblView reloadData];

 }

-(void)DisplayMatchSearch{

 if (searchStr && searchStr.length) {
   //temp array

    arrLocation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   //parsed array  self.buildingsArray

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.buildingsArray)
    {
        if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:searchStr options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
            [arrLocation addObject:dictionary];

        }
    }

    [tblview reloadData];

   }

}
```